# Spring MVC and X-HTTP-Method-Override parameter

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC, and I have a function to update a user's profile:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{userName}" + EndPoints.USER_PROFILE,
    method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> updateUserProfile(
    @PathVariable String userName, @RequestBody UserProfileDto userProfileDto) {
    // Process update user's profile
}
```

I've started using JMeter, and for some reason they have a problem with sending a PUT request with a body (either in a request body or using a request parameter hack).

I know that in Jersey you can add a filter to process the X-HTTP-Method-Override request parameter, so that you can send a POST request and override it using the header parameter.

Is there any way to do this in Spring MVC?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spring MVC has the [HiddenHttpMethodFilter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.html) which allows you to include a request parameter (`_method`) to override the http method. You just need to add the filter into your filter chain in web.xml.

I'm not aware of an out-of-the-box solution to use the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header, but you can create a filter similar to the `HiddenHttpMethodFilter` yourself which uses the header to change the value rather than the request parameter.

Answer (score 9):

You can use this class as a filter:

```
public class HttpMethodOverrideHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
  private static final String X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER = "X-HTTP-Method-Override";

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    String headerValue = request.getHeader(X_HTTP_METHOD_OVERRIDE_HEADER);
    if (RequestMethod.POST.name().equals(request.getMethod()) && StringUtils.hasLength(headerValue)) {
      String method = headerValue.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH);
      HttpServletRequest wrapper = new HttpMethodRequestWrapper(request, method);
      filterChain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
    }
    else {
      filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
  }

  private static class HttpMethodRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private final String method;

    public HttpMethodRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request, String method) {
      super(request);
      this.method = method;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMethod() {
      return this.method;
    }
  }
}
```

Source: http://blogs.isostech.com/web-application-development/put-delete-requests-yui3-spring-mvc/